# When I'm using second operator right after the first, it undo the first operator result

Tags: python, bpy

There's my first operator, it do many things but you have to know, that it does makes vertex group "Heel".

```
class HEEL_OT_cut_heel(bpy.types.Operator):
    """Go to -Z pointview, then select scan object and press this button to create a heel."""
    bl_label = "Cut heel"
    bl_idname = "mesh.cut_heel_operator"
    
    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None
    
    def execute(self, context):
    
    ...

    group_heel = cut_and_clean(scan, curve)
    group_heel.name = 'Heel'

    ...

    return {'FINISHED'}
```

There's my second operator:

```
class HEEL_OT_elongate_heel(bpy.types.Operator):
    """If scan have hell vertex group, press this button to enlongate it"""
    bl_label = 'Elongate heel'
    bl_idname = 'mesh.elongate_heel_operator'
    bl_options = {'REGISTER', 'UNDO'}

    @classmethod
    def poll(cls, context):
        return context.active_object is not None

    transition_value: bpy.props.FloatProperty(
        default = 15,
        soft_min = 10,
        soft_max = 25
    )

    def get_transition_value(self):
        return self.transition_value

    def set_transition_value(self, x):
        self.transition_value = x

    def invoke(self, context, event):
        self.set_transition_value(bpy.context.scene.heel_transition_value)

        return self.execute(context)

    def execute(self, context):
        scan = bpy.context.active_object

        if scan.mode != 'OBJECT':
            bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

        if validation_scan(scan):
            self.report({'ERROR'}, "Object is not configurated.")
            return {'CANCELLED'}
        
        group_heel = scan.vertex_groups.get("Heel")
        if not group_heel:
            self.report({'ERROR'}, "Object don't have 'Heel' vertex group.")
            return {'CANCELLED'}

        select_vertex_group(scan, group_heel)
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')
        # Scale to cursor 
        bpy.context.scene.cursor.location[2] = get_min_z(scan)
        bpy.context.scene.tool_settings.transform_pivot_point = 'CURSOR'
        
        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'EDIT')  

        bpy.ops.transform.resize(
            value=(1, 1, 0), 
            orient_type='GLOBAL',
            orient_matrix_type='GLOBAL', 
            constraint_axis=(True, True, True), 
            mirror=True, 
            use_proportional_edit=True, 
            proportional_edit_falloff='SHARP', 
            proportional_size = self.get_transition_value(), 
            use_proportional_connected=True
        )

        bpy.ops.object.mode_set(mode = 'OBJECT')

        bpy.context.scene.heel_transition_value = self.get_transition_value()
        return {'FINISHED'}
```

When I use first operator on active object and then without other action (move, scale, etc.) I use second operator, it do take those both actions as one. This is how I do understand this. When I try to undo it with Ctrl + Z shortcut, then I get back before vertex group "Heel" has been assigned. And when I try change transition_value in Redo Panel, second operator also didn't get vertex group "Heel", because it wasn't there.

I'm still learning Blender library, so if you see something *ugly* in my code, please, let me know.

Comment: I forget about bl_option = {'REGISTER'} in first operator.

Comment: This solution didn't solve my problem.